# how to retrive select tag value in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

hello i am devloping new jsp web site and i want to retrieve value from drop downlist my code is given below.

```
                   <tr><td>Room Name</td><td><input type="text" name="roomname"></td></tr>

                 <tr><td>Room Type</td><td><select id="roomtypeid" name="roomtypeid">
                    <option  value="2L">Conference(1-25 user) </option>
                    <option  value="1L">restricted(1-50 user) </option>
                    <option  value="0L">interview (1-1 meeting with recording) </option>
                </select>
```

in another page i am trying to get value of textbox like below.

```
             java.lang.String name =request.getParameter("roomname");
```

this run perfectly but when i try to get value from dropdown. i get null value.i try following code.

```
 out.println("your selection is..." + request.getParameter("roomtyperoomtypeid"));
```

kindly help me how to retrive value from dropdown.

Comment: The name is `roomtypeid` !

Comment: yes. i have mention in question also.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: hahaha... He has already mentioned it in his question dear...

Comment: @improver My point was he should use `roomtypeid` instaed of some random string to fetch the parameter.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: I did understood, but OP didn't :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should

```
out.println("your selection is..." + request.getParameter("roomtyperoomtypeid"));
```

actually be:

```
out.println("your selection is..." + request.getParameter("roomtypeid"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
request.getParameter("roomtyperoomtypeid"))
```

To:

```
request.getParameter("roomtypeid"))
```

You were trying to access non-existing element, so null pointer exception.

Comment: by mistak i have do past two times. roomtype.  :) thannk you ..